# Mailchimp List API Function - Returning a list of subscribers with Email address

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am looking to develop a simple plug-in or static page invoking the Mailchimp SDK to be able to make list downloads available within the Wordpress dashboard (optimally but not required) of current Mailchimp list subscribers without having to give the API key out nor direct access to Mailchimp.

I want to do this as we collaborate with other groups at times and I would like to provide this function to a certain level of user within Wordpress to do anytime, but it be preferably transparent to them the API and other functions.

Though really when it comes down to it I want to just export a list without having to also log into Mailchimp, even if that means it is me doing it.

I have looked at several Mailchimp plug-ins and non seem to have a "Export List" function, just sync with Wordpress users and subscribe functions, so it seems I need to make something myself.

I have attempted to just grab the piece of [sample code provided under the list function](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list.func.php) and put it in a PHP file with my API & list ID information, but it only returned a blank screen. So I am obviously missing something.

I am looking to build something basic at first but have not worked with the API before, is there something I specifically need to add or reference to the example code referenced above to have it return results?

I would appreciate some assistance and direction on this topic such as more complete example code, what additional things I need to do, or being direct to something that already provides this if I am trying to reinvent the wheel.

*Note: NOT My real APIKEY or ListID.*  The code is exactly copy and past from the above link with the API and list code added.

```
$apikey = 'c9db3c02b25c370cda1c31a5c8aacd5-us1';
$list_id = '123456';
$chunk_size = 4096; //in bytes
$url = 'http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list?apikey='.$apikey.'&id='.$list_id;

/** a more robust client can be built using fsockopen **/
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if (!$handle) {
  echo "failed to access url\n";
} else {
  $i = 0;
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
    if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);
      if ($i==0){
        //store the header row
        $header = $obj;
      } else {
        //echo, write to a file, queue a job, etc.
        echo $header[0].': '.$obj[0]."\n";
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: @veve Updated with code used.

Comment: Is the end of your API key -us1 ? The end of the API key should be the same as the beginning of the URL. If it ends on -us7, your url should start with http://us7.api....